# Different maven compiler versions for test and main

Tags: java, maven, compiler-construction, maven-2, maven-3

How can I configure the maven compiler to use java 5 for my test code and java 1.4 for my main code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to set compliance to the relevant Java version, you can configure the compiler plugin for each execution. Assuming Maven is using a JDK at least as current as the highest version you specify. By using properties you can override that configuration on the commandline or in a child if needed:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>${compileSource}</source>
    <target>${compileSource}</target>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>${testCompileSource}</source>
        <target>${testCompileSource}</target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
<properties>
  <compileSource>1.4</compileSource>
  <testCompileSource>1.5</testCompileSource>
</properties>
```

If you mean using different **compilers**, that's a bit more involved. as you need to specify the path to the JDK and what compiler version you're using. Again these can be defined in properties. Though you may want to define them in your settings.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>${compileSource}</source>
    <target>${compileSource}</target>
    <executable>${compileJdkPath}/bin/javac</executable>
    <compilerVersion>${compileSource}</compilerVersion>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test-compile</id>
      <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>${testCompileSource}</source>
        <target>${testCompileSource}</target>
        <executable>${testCompileJdkPath}/bin/javac</executable>
        <compilerVersion>${testCompileSource}</compilerVersion>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
...
<properties>
  <compileSource>1.4</compileSource>
  <testCompileSource>1.5</testCompileSource>
  <compileJdkPath>path/to/jdk</compileJdkPath>
  <testCompileJdkPath>path/to/test/jdk<testCompileJdkPath>
</properties>
```

Note it might make sense to define the compiler configurations in profiles, one for each JDK you support, so that your normal builds don't rely on properties being set.

Also, **in Maven 3.x, you need to include the `fork` parameter when specifying the executable,** e.g.:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-testCompile</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <executable>${testCompileJdkPath}/bin/javac</executable>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>            
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: When I attempt the first example with source and target version `1.8` for tests and `1.7` for main code, the compilation succeeds when `mvn compile` is run separately from `mvn test-compile`, but in commands such as `mvn compile test-compile` or, more simply, `mvn test-compile` (where `compile` is pulled in) the main configuration with `<source>1.7</source>` seems to take precedence, and it fails.

Comment: The solution is that it is `<id>default-testCompile</id>` that overrides the default behavior. The above answer adds an additional execution.

Comment: Forgive my lack of understanding about executions. Will this cause the main application code to be compiled to the same target version as the test code if executing maven tests? Or will the main and test sources have different target bytecode versions?

Comment: @ChrisBetti That depends on what the <target> and <testTarget> configuration options are set to.  The compiler used does not dictate the bytecode version used.

Answer (score 20):

I had no luck with the accepted answer compiling java 7 source and java 8 test sources using the `maven-compiler-plugin`, version 3.5.1. Because the compile plugin used the source / target parameter for both, main and test sources.

But I found out, there are separate configuration parameters for the test source and target.

So for me the solution that worked was

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Where are these settings `<testSource>` and `<testTarget>` documented? I can't find them at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html .

Comment: They belong to the testCompile goal https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#testSource

Comment: Wow, so you mean I can skip the plugin declaration altogether and use the `maven.compiler.testSource` and `maven.compiler.testTarget` user properties?! Or on Java 9 or later just use the `maven.compiler.testRelease` property!?? I haven't tested it yet, but wow, that is very nice, thanks!!!

Comment: Unfortunately this is broken in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464505

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at least for my case.

I am writing a library that needs to be Java 1.7 compatible but relies on the `nashorn` engine in JDK 8 to test some of its features, which is a perfect reason for using different compiler/jdk version for `main` and `test`.

When talking about using different compiler/JRE version for main and test, say version `A` for `main` and version `B` for `test` and `A` is strictly smaller than `B`, we really want to achieve the following:

1. Make the IDE (in my case, the `Eclipse`) use the JDK version `B` during development for not introducing compilation error (red cross on your project icon).
2. Make JUnit tests runnable from within your IDE.
3. Make JUnit tests runnable from command line through `mvn clean test` which is required for releasing.
4. Compile sources in `main` using JRE `A`, which enables automatic detection of using new features from JDK `B`.
5. Free use of new features / new APIs from JDK `B` in test cases codes.

And the following pom declaration works (for example let `A = 1.7` and `B = 1.8`):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                      <id>default-compile</id>
                      <configuration>
                         <compilerArguments>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                         </compilerArguments>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                      <id>default-testCompile</id>
                      <configuration>
                         <compilerArguments>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                         </compilerArguments>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Firstly, `<source>1.8</source> <target>1.8</target>` is a must to make Eclipse happy and using 1.8 for the project itself, as others pointed out that Eclipse has a still pending bug and does not support different JDK version in a single project natively.

Secondly, use `<execution>` to override the `source` and `target` arguments during source compilation and test source compilation. `default-compile` and `default-testCompile` are special names for compiler plugin.

Thirdly, be sure to use `compilerArguments` but not `compilerArgs`. As far as I know, only `compilerArguments` can be used to override argument settings during runtime.