# How to write Junit with Java 1.7 while running base code with 1.6

Tags: java, junit, version-compatibility

I would like to use java 7 in my tests and java 6 for the code. How to achieve this?

Comment: It's a really bad idea, IMHO.

Comment: If you have any control over the environments, then it'd make sense to get them both on the same JDK version.

Comment: I don't have any control. On code I'm dependent on java 1.6 and in test I want to use newer syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different maven compiler versions for test and main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213897/different-maven-compiler-versions-for-test-and-main)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set source and target in the execution phase `testCompile` of the `maven-compiler-plugin`. So try something like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>testCompileWithJDK7</id>
           <phase>test-compile</phase>
           <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>              
           </configuration> 
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the jvm that is used by the maven-surefire-plugin to point to the java 7 executable.

See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#jvm

Comment: Maven fails on: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project MyProject: Compilation failure`

Comment: You should set the source and target properties of the maven-compiler-plugin to 1.6 and ensure that the mvn is started using a jdk 6. It seems that your source code is not compatible with the jdk version you started the mvn build. Could you please update the question and add: jdk mvn is started with, maven-compiler-plugin config, maven-surefire-plugin config